# Ellipse equations paradox

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, conic-sections

We know that an ellipse can be plotted in cartesian coordinates using the following parametric function:
$$ ellipsePoint(\theta)=\left[\begin{array}{c}a \cdot \cos(\theta)\\b \cdot \sin(\theta)\end{array}\right], 0\leqslant \theta \lt 2\pi $$

I have rewritten it as an equation in polar coordinates:

$$ r=distance(ellipsePoint(\theta), \left[\begin{array}{c}0\\0\end{array}\right])=distance(\left[\begin{array}{c}a \cdot \cos(\theta)\\b \cdot \sin(\theta)\end{array}\right], \left[\begin{array}{c}0\\0\end{array}\right])=\sqrt{a^2 \cdot \cos(\theta)^2+b^2 \cdot \sin(\theta)^2} $$

However, plotting values of the $ ellipsePoint $ function and plotting the solutions of the second equation result in different graphs:

[image]

Why is it so? Have I done something incorrectly?

Comment: The parameter $\theta$ in your parametric equation is not equal to the angle $\theta$ of polar coordinates.  So (as you saw) you get something wrong if you assume it is.

Comment: That was the key issue! I knew that the $t$ variable in the $\left[ \begin{array}{c}x\\y\end{array}\right](t)=\left[ \begin{array}{c}r\cos(t)\\r\sin(t)\end{array}\right] $ parametric function representing a circle with radius $r$ corresponds to the $\theta$ angle of the section connecting $\left[ \begin{array}{c}x\\y\end{array}\right]$ to $\left[ \begin{array}{c}0\\0\end{array}\right]$ with respect to the X axis anticlockwise.

Comment: So I thought intuitively the similar thing occurs with the ellipse parametric function, and now it turned out that I was wrong. It's good to become aware of things like this and improve our mathematical intuition :)

Comment: @GEdgar here we have an explicit graphical proof: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/utrajanwg6

Answer (score 2):

Switching to polar coordinates,

$$\rho=\sqrt{a^2\cos^2t+b^2\sin^2t},\\\tan\theta=\frac ba\tan t.$$

After elimination of $t$,

$$\rho=\sqrt{a^2\cos^2\left(\arctan\left(\frac ab\tan\theta\right)\right)+b^2\sin^2\left(\arctan\left(\frac ab\tan\theta\right)\right)}
\\=\sqrt{a^2\frac1{\dfrac{a^2}{b^2}\tan^2\theta+1}+b^2\frac{\dfrac{a^2}{b^2}\tan^2\theta}{\dfrac{a^2}{b^2}\tan^2\theta+1}}
\\=\sqrt{\frac{a^2b^2}{a^2\sin^2\theta+b^2\cos^2\theta}}
.$$

Note that with $a=b=r$, this simplifies to $r$, as expected. The values at multiples of $\dfrac\pi2$ are also correct.

Comment: You should substitute $\tan t=(a/b)\tan\theta$, you exchanged $a$ and $b$.

Comment: @Aretino: you are quite right. After the fix, the answer is more likely. My checks were insufficient :-(